# Granting a user access to all databases in Postgres cluster

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have only seen examples of SQL statements granting users access to one database in a Postgres cluster at a time. Is there a way to grant a non-superuser access to all databases and their tables including future databases that get created in the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Since PostgreSQL v14, this is fairly easy, and you can use the following SQL script:

```
-- exempt the user from row level security
ALTER ROLE seeall BYPASSRLS;
-- allow the user to read all data
GRANT read_all_data TO seeall;
```

If you want write access as well, there is also a predefined role `pg_write_all_data`.

This relies on the fact that by default, everybody has the `CONNECT` privilege on databases. Of course you also have to configure `pg_hba.conf` to allow access.

And in case you wonder: no, before v14 you have to grant access to all objects individually. Group roles help with that.